# How to use FileProvider in Uri.parse(file://" + filex.toString()) & Java.lang.RuntimeException Error Receiving BroadCast Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent

How to use `FileProvider` for not getting error in `android API >= 24`?
I've tried `FileProvider` but it's still getting error...
Here is my source code

```
if(vid.equals("")) {
    inFileName = img.substring(img.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File filex = new File(sdcard, inDir + "/" + "IMAGE_" + inFileName);
    if(filex.exists()) {
        if (inDialog.isShowing())
            inDialog.dismiss();

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + filex.toString());
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
        inContext.startActivity(i);
    } else {
        inTmp = Uri.parse(img);
        Image_DownloadId = DownloadData(inTmp, "IMAGE_" + inFileName);
    }
}
```

First log

```
android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/Images/IMAGE_26072028_383759662086144_8624202031520808960_n.jpg exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
```

This error because of using `android api >= 24` and need to use `FileProvider`, so I try to use it..
this line is a little bit confusing because of using `toString` method
`Uri.parse("file://" + filex.toString())`

Here is what I'm trying to do

```
if(vid.equals("")) {
inFileName = img.substring(img.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File filex = new File(sdcard, inDir + "/" + "IMAGE_" + inFileName);
if(filex.exists()) {
    if (inDialog.isShowing())
        inDialog.dismiss();

    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(inContext, inContext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", new File("file://" + filex.toString()));
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    inContext.startActivity(i);
} else {
    inTmp = Uri.parse(img);
    Image_DownloadId = DownloadData(inTmp, "IMAGE_" + inFileName);
}
```

The application still getting force close.

Here is the log

```
01-14 17:48:24.288 23382-23382/com.my.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.my.app, PID: 23382
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /file:/storage/emulated/0/Images/IMAGE_26072028_383759662086144_8624202031520808960_n.jpg
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:711)
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:400)
    at com.my.app.App$Loading$1.onClick(Saver.java:128)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5619)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22295)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6321)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
```

Got another error in this line

```
String filename = cursor.getString(filenameIndex);
BroadcastReceiver downloadReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //check if the broadcast message is for our Enqueued download
        long referenceId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);

        if(referenceId == Image_DownloadId) {

            DownloadManager.Query ImageDownloadQuery = new DownloadManager.Query();
            //set the query filter to our previously Enqueued download
            ImageDownloadQuery.setFilterById(Image_DownloadId);

            //Query the download manager about downloads that have been requested.
            Cursor cursor = downloadManager.query(ImageDownloadQuery);
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                int filenameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME);
                String filename = cursor.getString(filenameIndex);
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://" + filename);

                Intent i = new Intent();
                if(inTenTipe.equals("repost")) {
                    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                    i.setType("image/*");
                }else {
                    i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
                }

                try {
                    if (inDialog.isShowing())
                        inDialog.dismiss();
                    inContext.startActivity(i);
                } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                    File file = new File(filename);
                    boolean deleted = file.delete();
                    Image_DownloadId = DownloadData(inTmp, "IMAGE_" + inFileName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Log

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.my.app, PID: 29139
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE flg=0x10 pkg=com.my.app (has extras) } in com.my.app.APP$1@cc58ede
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:1140)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6321)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
    Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME is deprecated; use ContentResolver.openFileDescriptor() instead
        at android.app.DownloadManager$CursorTranslator.getString(DownloadManager.java:1791)
        at com.my.app.App$1.onReceive(Saver.java:616)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:1130)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6321) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:880) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:770)
```

Comment: post the full stacktrace

Comment: the log updated... @pskink

Comment: your error is: `Failed to find configured root that contains [...]`, see https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing.html and https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html

Comment: got another error after editing a little bit @pskink